# File fields are not indexed - apache solr attachments

Tags: 7, search

For indexing files, I enabled the module like apache solr attachments. In my stage enviroment, files are getting indexed. Search results shows the file results.

In apache solr index also no of fields indexed are 100 (includes ss_filemime,ss_filesize etc)

But In my production enviroment, files are not getting indexed. In apache solr index i cant find the fields like (ss_filemime,ss_filesize) . I uninstalled and again installed still it doesnt index.

The same thing is working in stage. So i cant reproduce the issue.

It would be helpful if someone have idea to fix it.